# Swift: Alamofire HTTP Proxy

Tags: swift, alamofire, nsurlsession, http-proxy, socks

I can't seem a to find a way to create http requests using proxies, let say i have a Sock5 proxy or HTTP Proxy how would i go about creating a GET/POST request via a proxy, without having to apply the proxy to the system.

I only want the single request to go through a proxy.

Let's say i create a http request using Alamofire, then the request would go through my ip address, but what if i want to apply a http proxy or socks5 proxy to send the request through.

Let's say I make a request like that:

```
    Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { response in

      if let JSON = response.result.value {
         print("JSON: \(JSON)")
      }

    }
```

How would i apply the http or socks proxy to this request?
Can't seem to find anything about it.

Comment: What does Alamofire's documentation about proxy?  Have you made an effort?

Comment: Alamofire's documentation doesn't mention anything abount proxies, and or socks. Wouldn't be asking here, unless i can't solve the problem my self.

Comment: It says "Another way to override the default implementation of the SessionDelegate is to subclass it. Subclassing allows you completely customize the behavior of the API or to create a proxy for the API and still use the default implementation. Creating a proxy allows you to log events, emit notifications, provide pre and post hook implementations, etc. Here's a quick example of subclassing the SessionDelegate and logging a message when a redirect occurs."

Comment: Did you even read my problem? This has nothing to do with HTTP Proxies and or Sock Proxies.

Comment: @steelzeh when you make a request to a http proxy you don't  do get/post, you use connect. Proxy then takes care of connecting you to the end host by using get/post request.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [this](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/282) thread:

You create proxy details:

```
 struct ProxyItem: Equatable, Hashable {
            let host: String
            let port: String
            let HTTPOnly = true

            var hashValue: Int {
                return host.hashValue ^ port.hashValue
            }
        }
```

then create proxy configuration

```
var proxyConfiguration = [NSObject: AnyObject]()
proxyConfiguration[kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPProxy] = item.host
proxyConfiguration[kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPPort] = port
proxyConfiguration[kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPEnable] = 1
```

set the Alamo configuration:

```
let sessionConfiguration = AFManager.sharedInstance.session.configuration
sessionConfiguration.connectionProxyDictionary = proxyConfiguration
```

Create an alamo manager from this configuration:

```
manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: sessionConfiguration)
```

Finally use the manager to connect to your proxy:

```
 manager.request(.GET, urlString)
.response {
    (request, response, data, error) in

    if let response = response {
        var statusCode = response.statusCode
        println("-->statusCode: \(statusCode)")
    }

    if (error == nil) {
        var serializationError: NSError?
        let jsonData: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data! as! NSData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &serializationError)

        var parser: Parser = Parser()
        let menu: Menu = parser.parseMenuJSON(jsonData)

        var dataAccess: DataAccess = DataAccess.sharedInstance
        dataAccess.addMenu(menu)
    } else {
        println("Webservice error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, will test this out.